# Only one square for the white king

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

Consider this position.

[image]

It is white's turn to move. Your job is to place the white king so that white have an overwhelming (winning) advantage. Where is it?

Please note that:

- While Queen usually wins against a bishop and knight, it is possible (yet rare) for [a bishop and knight to hold a draw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOzdwycf8y0). The position won't happen in this game if both sides play perfectly for any position of the white king and you don't have to worry about it.
- A queen always win [against a bishop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3FtKrCBUWw), or [against a knight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq5OduYoNqI). This counts as an overwhelming advantage.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note that without their king, White’s plan would be

> to play 1. Ne7!. If Black chooses to save their queen, White responds with 2. Ng6# if the queen move does not protect g6, and 2. Qg8# otherwise. In the special case 1... Qe8, White plays 2. Qg8+ Qxg8 3. Ng6#, a smothered mate.

Thus, the aforementioned sequence of moves will

> guarantee White will win Black’s queen, and hence win the game, as long as Black cannot check the White king after the first move. So we need to place the White king so that it’s impossible for Black to put it in check without losing their queen.

The only square White’s king can be in that satisfies the constraint is

> **b1**. The only possible checking moves Black can make after Ne7 are Qc1+, Qc2+, and Qf5+, all of which result in the loss of the queen and the preservation of the advantage.

Comment: Ugh! You beat me to it in by seconds!

Comment: Right, so you are allowed to move the knight rather than king. I found "Your job is to place the white king..." misleading.  The question might as well been: "What moves should white make to win?"

Answer (score 19):

HTM's answer is very nice and must be what's intended here. But I'm not quite seeing why the puzzle isn't cooked as follows:

> if the WK is on any square adjacent to the BQ, white can play Kxc8. While Q versus BN is sometimes drawn, surely QN versus BN has to be enough to win easily?

Comment: I guess perhaps adding a condition that the king can’t be in check solves this issue

Comment: I think the fact that it says "one" position eliminates the different squares adjacent to the black queen and probably just clarification needed on the part on the OP. As a quick aside, wouldn't this answer be more appropriate as a comment in either HTM's answer or to the question?

Comment: It's an alternative answer (or, more precisely, five of them). The puzzle says one position and clearly intends there to be just one, but if I'm correct then there are actually six possible answers. (But I could well be incorrect; maybe winning with KQN versus KBN is harder than it seems like it should be.)

Comment: Hm okay. The wording seemed a little more like a comment rather than an answer, though I do see your point. I would've flagged it had you not been a mod, but I figured you knew what you were doing and so decided to ask for clarification instead of making myself look dumb. Idk though, I mean I guess you could add more? Like the possible threat of back rank checkmate after capturing the queen or the lingering threat of the smothered mate?

Comment: I like this answer and it seemed the obvious choice.  If it's white to move, then there's no reason white can't be in check.

Comment: The intended answer is much cleverer, though.

Comment: [SPOILER] The inspiration for this puzzle came when I was playing around with smothered mate puzzles. When I saw this position, I find it is a coincidence that the King is placed such that it couldn't be checked by the Queen and worked backward from there. It never dawn on me that the King can just capture the Queen right away so kuddo to you.

Answer (score 0):

Without analysing this too deeply, I would say

> C4

Which sounds counter-intuitive, but

> Neither the king nor knight have much power on their own - they need each other to have any chance of success. If they are far apart, the knight can be picked off easily resulting in checkmate for the remaining king.

Comment: This answer was assuming the question is asking about a single move by the white king, not a long term strategy for white (a position the king cannot reach in 1 move).

Comment: I reworded the question. The question ask for a position of the white king for white to move and win, not necessary where the white king should "move."

Comment: Well, my answer would be the same. But given black has several options to move still, I don’t see how this (or any move from the white king) results in winning. I guess I need think laterally?

Comment: C4 wouldn't be a very good placement in the first place: the king gets in the way between the knight and the queen, which hinders the threat that white has on the diagonal should the knight move.

Comment: And that is why I don't win at chess :)

Comment: Actually, with white king on c4 the position seems to be drawn, since he is there in check, so the only possibilities are 1. Kb5 Qb8+ 2.Nb6 (otherwise Black trades queens, as well after 1. Kb4) 2... Bd4, and as White cannot give check, Black forces bishop-knight trade and draws. Nearly the same is 1. Kd3 Qh3+ 2.Ne3 Bh6. Although now the white queen *can* give check (by e.g. 3.Qb8+), she cannot alone drive the black king off from his minor pieces.

Comment: @trolley813 that feels almost philosophical